# Hexadecimal value in android xml file

Tags: android, xml, hex, android-preferences

I need to keep an hexadecimal value in my application's preferences, with *0x* prefix.

I specified default value of the preference as *0x0A*,

```
android:defaultValue="0x0A"
```

but when I'm trying to retrieve this value I get *"0xa".*

Why is that and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: It is because you don't need leading zeros. I recommend that you store hex values as strings. And then parse them like this: `Long.parseLong("0A", 16);`

Comment: Try to replace 0x0A with #0A

Comment: @MatjažMav - Yeah, I know how to do it in java code, but acutally I need to specify this value in xml.

Comment: @krystian71115 - already tried this, didn't help.

Comment: Paste fragment of code when you getting this value

Comment: The problem is that Resources convert my value. I get log:                    06-30 14:14:03.227: W/Resources(7935): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x1 a=-1}
I want to somehow avoid that.

Comment: What the preference type?